# How to use execve for exporting environment variables

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out how to export this environmental variables from my minishell to bash.  Nothing happens when I use this code to export.  Am I doing something wrong

```
      if(strcmp(istring, "myexport") ==0)     //This command shows parent enviornment
  {
      char * const *junk;
      execve("/bin/bash" , junk , myexp);
      return(1);
  }
```

Comment: You do not initialize `junk`, why? What is `myexp`?

Comment: The changes you make only apply while that copy of bash is executing.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
char *const argv = { "-c", "env", 0 };
char *const env = { "PATH=/bin", "USER=wibble", 0 };

execve("/bin/bash", argv, env);
```

And of course you can fetch things our of the existing environment by using `extern char **environ;` or `getenv` to construct the environment for the new binary/script.

Comment: argv and env should be string arrays, you have them declared as constant strings.

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to run `bash` in order to set the environment in your shell, you are misunderstanding how the environment is set.

There are the coding problems identified in the other answers:

- You do not initialize `junk`.
- You do not show how you initialize `myexp`.

Assuming you get past those issues, though, the deeper one is that the child process cannot affect the environment of the parent process.  When a shell exports an environment variable, it does so by adjusting a list that is supplied to each command it executes, but it is handled inside the shell, not by executing any external command.

Also, if the fragment shown is not run in a child process (after a `fork()`), then you have another problem; `execve()` does not return when the command executes successfully.

So, to export an environment variable, the change is made in the main shell, not in a sub-process.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an uninitialized pointer as the second argument to `execve`—most likely, that will fail with `EFAULT`, but if it does somehow magically succeed, `bash` is going to see garbage in its `argv` array of arguments and do something strange (most likely complain that some junk file doesn't exist).

If you don't want to pass any arguments, pass in a pointer to `NULL`, but it's good practice to at least pass in the name of the program being executed as `argv[0]`:

```
char *const argv[] = {"bash", NULL};
execve("/bin/bash", argv, myexp);
```

Also, what is `myexp`?  Is it a pointer to a `NULL`-terminated array of pointers to strings of the form `FOO=BAR`?

Comment: Thank you.  That is what myexp is.  I tried your code but it is still not working.myexp:                                  
   for(i=0; i<100; i++)
   {
       myexp[100] = NULL;
   }